# llenar un DataGridView a partir de la resta de otros 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, datagridview

Tengo un `DataGridView1` con la misma cantidad de filas y columnas que un `DataGridView2`, ambos se llenan desde la BD sin problema a partir de criterios de búsqueda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
necesito llenar cada fila del `DataGridView3` con el resultado de una resta de los anteriores al presionar un botón.
Pseudocódigo:

> DataGridView3.C1 = DataGridView2.C3 - DataGridView1.C3
> DataGridView3.C2 = DataGridView2.C4 - DataGridView1.C4

Solo he logrado recorrer un `DataGridView` a la vez, necesito recorrer los `DataGridView` 1 y 2 en paralelo para llenar el 3.
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Deja el código de lo que estas intentando, sino ayudarte es muy difícil!

Comment: añade el código, para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de todo no era tan complicado como pensaba, no era necesario utilizar un dataSource para el dataGridView3, lo hice directo con una fila temporal dentro de un for y funciona correctamente, si alguien estaba esperando respuesta aquí está como lo sulucioné, olvidé responder antes

```
 for (int i = 1; i < DATA1_dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                        decimal enc_REQ1 = Convert.ToDecimal(DATA1_dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ENC_REQUERIDO"].Value);
                        decimal enc_REQ2 = Convert.ToDecimal(DATA2_dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["ENC_REQUERIDO"].Value);
                        decimal COMP_ENC_REQ = enc_REQ2 - enc_REQ1;

                        decimal enc_COL1 = Convert.ToDecimal(DATA1_dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ENC_COLOCADO"].Value);
                        decimal enc_COL2 = Convert.ToDecimal(DATA2_dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells["ENC_COLOCADO"].Value);
                        decimal COMP_ENC_COL = enc_COL2 - enc_COL1;

                        DataRow _tempRow1 = data3_dataTable.NewRow();
                        _tempRow1["Banco"] = banco1;
                        _tempRow1["Encaje Requerido"] = COMP_ENC_REQ;
                        _tempRow1["Encaje Colocado"] = COMP_ENC_COL;
                        data3_dataTable.Rows.Add(_tempRow1);

                }
```